# How to extract public key from private key using openssl in C

Tags: c, openssl

I know in command line that given a pem file of private key, you can extract the public key from it.

Wondering how the similar function can be achieved using openssl's C library?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! What have you already tried? What concrete problems have you encountered? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

First, read the key:

```
EVP_PKEY *key;
FILE *fpkey;
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
key = EVP_PKEY_new();
fpkey = fopen ("key.pem", "r");
PEM_read_PrivateKey(fpkey, &key, NULL, NULL);
fclose(fpkey);
```

Now that you have the `EVP_PKEY` structure, you can save the public key:

```
FILE* fppubkey = fopen("pubkey.pem", "wb");
PEM_write_PUBKEY(fppubkey, key);
fclose(fppubkey);
```

Make sure to add error checking.

Comment: How to extract it in EVP_PKEY* without saving it to file?